# Multi-theaded Numpy inserts

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I am considering creating a numpy table as key/value database. 
The inputs/update would be multi-theaded.

Exploring the idea, 
Problem: would GIL stop theads and only allow one update at time.
Problem: can numpy table (tablespace) be mutlitheaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some numpy functions are not atomic, so if two threads were to operate on the same array by calling some non-atomic numpy functions, then the array will become mangled because the order of operations will be mixed up in some non-anticipated way.

There are many examples, but just to be concrete, [numpy.apply_along_axis](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L11) is a long sequence of Python statements, clearly not atomic.

The GIL will not help you since it could stop one thread while it is only partly through some non-atomic numpy function, then start another thread which is operating on the same array...

So to be thread-safe, you would need to use a `threading.Lock` and only operate on the array after the Lock has been acquired:

```
with lock:
    arr = ...
```

Having to use a lock everywhere calls into question whether there is any benefit to having multiple threads operating on same array. Note that sometimes 
multithreading on a CPU-bound problem [may result in slower performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403768/parallelism-in-python-isnt-working-right/8404061#8404061) than a comparable single-threaded version.

See also the [ParallelProgramming with numpy and scipy wiki page](http://wiki.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming) for more alternatives and discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I ve just needed that so I wrote it..
Going to try it now so not sure if it works as expected yet..

```
class LockedNumpyArray(object):
    """
    Thread safe numpy array
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.val = None

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        self.lock.acquire()
        if self.val != None:
            ret_val = self.val.copy()
        else:
            ret_val = None
        self.lock.release()
        # print('getting', ret_val)
        return ret_val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.lock.acquire()
        # print('setting', val)
        self.val = val.copy()
        self.lock.release()
```

That is the class for numpy array. Then I have a class for controlling because later I want to have more thread safe numpy arrays operating.

```
class CaptureControl():
    """
    Shared class to control source capture execution
    """
    frame = LockedNumpyArray()

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.frame)
        self.frame = np.array([2])
        print(self.frame)
```

In the end I put an instance of this CaptureControl class into thread(s) as follows.

```
class CaptureThread(threading.Thread):
    """
    Thread running source capturing
    """
    def __init__(self, capture_control):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.capture_control = capture_control
        self.sleepTime = 0.01
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.capture_control.capture_frame()
            time.sleep(self.sleepTime)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    capture_control = CaptureControl()
    capture_thread = CaptureThread(capture_control)
    capture_thread.start()
```

I will be glad if anyone shared any thoughts about this solution, not including the time.sleep in thread run function as this is just an example ;).