# mysql read -> process -> update, optimize for huge data

Tags: python, mysql, optimization, distributed-computing

I have a simple task. Read data from mysql -> perform some operation(not very heavy) -> then update back result into mysql DB`. With 20 different tables in a database (~600000 rows each).

I have written a python script using `ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)` to optimize overall execution time but it takes around 40 hours. I want to optimize it for next run.

I tried to run multiple instances of code but performance is not very significant. 
Is there any better approach to finish the task quickly like distributed code or something which anybody is aware of?

Minimalistic algo of code

```
conn.autocommit = True
ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)
```

1. read data and process tuple by tuple as follows
2. detect lanugage from sentences using TextBlob().detect_language()
3. update back into table

Comment: The answer to this lies somewhere between "yes, trivially" and "no, 40 hours is the best you can do". Which one it is exactly will depend on what you are doing exactly, so you should share (the relevant and minimalized parts of) your code, otherwise, unfortunately we can't help you much.

Comment: Profile the thing. If you don't know where you are wasting most of the time how can you make it better? Maybe its mysql maybe its the processing code. Also GIL only affects threading, you can multiprocess.

Comment: Thanks for adding some details. `TextBlob().detect_language()` sends a request to the google api. This will limit your throughput (and the mysql part will probably have about 0.01% effect on execution speed) . Try using a different software (with a local installation).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is create inserts and commits every few thousends row. Write everyting to the file. Remove indexes load data with mysql client and the creata index. Optimise server for bulk operations.

Parallelism in Python does NOT work. [Parallelism in python isn't working right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403768/parallelism-in-python-isnt-working-right)

Comment: No the fastest way to import data with MySQL is to use  `LOAD DATA INFILE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: putting data into file and then load file into db, will not it be a time constly operation ? I have used `LOAD DATA INFILE` before but I am not sure this is the suitable use-case here. By the time I will write data into file I can write into database directly, just my thought.

Comment: The overhead of writing the file to subsequently `LOAD` _may_ lead to it being slower.  OTOH, if you _already_ have the data in a file, `LOAD` is best.

Comment: The more I/O you do, the less parallelism you can get.  I would try two processes, each gathering 1000 rows, sending them to MySQL.  That ping-pong might effectively alternate between heavy-python usage and heavy-mysql usage.  Three processes might not run any faster.